# How do people create figures webcomics like xkcd and Oatmeal?

Tags: diagram

Like most internet denizens, I am also a big fan of XKCD, [Oatmeal](https://theoatmeal.com/comics/insight) and websites like [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#texas-ranges) which use humorous cartoons for expressing interesting ideas. What softwares do these guys use for creating such cartoonish (but complex) images?

Are there any open source softwares for this? I am famiilar with Inkscape of course, but I use these for general technical diagrams. For cartoonish diagrams which look as if they are hand-drawn, I don't know if Inkscape can recreate it (without a lot of pain and modulating the splines )

Also I am quite good at drawing cartoons with my hand on paper, but when it comes to doing the same with say Inkscape, my mouse does not allow me to perform fine touches. Are there special computer mice which graphic illustrators use for creating their content?

Comment: You could email and ask them ... I would guess a Wacom graphic tablet and whatever software comes with it (or supports it, if you don't get an answer here & have to search)